# payload is not valid JSON

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I'm using `curl` to send JSON to an API endpoint. However, somewhere in the bash chain it is getting messed up.

Is there something special to know about encoding with `curl`?

If I construct the payload like this:

```
 PAYLOAD='payload={"channel": "github", "username": "webhookbot", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:", "text": "'
 PAYLOAD+=$1
 PAYLOAD+=' " }'

 echo $PAYLOAD
 curl -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACKPOSTURL
 echo "sent"
```

I'll get back an error

> Payload was not valid JSONsent

however if i just hardwire to assign a variable with the output

```
PAYLOAD='payload={"channel": "github", "username": "webhookbot", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:", "text": "LAST_COMMIT Merge pull request #558 from dcsan/boteditor Boteditor " }'
```

then it will go through fine.

Is there something that a simple assignment is doing differently vs. concatenating strings? In the console the output looks identical.

FWIW some messages go through but content like this:

> LAST_COMMIT Merge pull request #558 from dcsan/boteditor Boteditor

will only go through if hardcoded in. so its not the other end afaican see, its something to do with the way messages are built.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to concatenate values into your variable. But `+=` is not the way to do so.

To concatenate strings in a variable you need to say:

```
PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD $1"
```

All together it would be something like the following. Note the need to use `"` so that the variable `$PAYLOAD` is expanded and the usage of `\"` to store a literal double quote:

```
PAYLOAD='payload={"channel": "github", "username": "webhookbot", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:", "text": "'
PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD $1 \" }"

echo "$PAYLOAD"
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACKPOSTURL
echo "sent"
```

Comment: the rest of the JSON needs " in tho, so that would make for a megaugly escaped string

Comment: You can play with `'` and `"`: use `"` whenever you need to expand a variable; use `'` otherwise. Edit: in fact, you need `"` every time, since we want to expand `$PAYLOAD`. However, for your given case it just needs one escaped `"`.

Comment: ok i tried with   
 PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD $1"
  PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD \""\}""
but still same error. i think maybe other end doesn't like slashes.

Comment: I think you are over escaping. `PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD \" }"` should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked from me from a bash script:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"text\": \"$2\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/$KEY
```

Notice the inner quotes are escaped, but the outer quotes are not.

FYI, adding:

```
set -x
```

at the beginning of a bash script will show you the actual commands being executed, and save a lot of guesswork.